# adjust behaviour off right column in three column layout

Tags: css

I would like some help with my three column layout.
I am not satisfied with the behaviour off the right column, because **it effects the center column if the browser is not maximized**. 
The right column needs to get smaller if the browser is made smaller, and not directly clip the center column.

---

I got the css from [this website](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm) and I use it for [this index page](http://taxi-bel.nl/)
I already try'd to adjust it, but it's kind of confusing.
Two containers are aligned from the right side and the others are aligned from the left side?

I have to say, this is a huge pain in the ass for me, because I need it fixed without screwing up the rest of the layout.
*Also the overflow hidden is not working in the right column, because the text jumps out?*

***Any help is appreciated!***

This is some off the css
( except for the header and footer )

```
/* column container */
.colmask { position:relative; clear:both; float:left; width:100%; overflow:hidden; }

/* general */
.colright,
.colmid,
.colleft {float:left;width:100%;position:relative;}


.col1,
.col2,
.col3 {float:left;position:relative;padding:0 0 1em 0;overflow:hidden;}

.threecol {background:#eee; }

/* width rightr column*/
.threecol .colmid {right:33.4%; background:#fff;}

/* width center column*/
.threecol .colleft {right:33%;  background:#f4f4f4; }

/* width center column content */
.threecol .col1 {width:30%; left:101.5%;/*background:#fff004;*/}

/* width left column content */
.threecol .col2 {width:32.2%;   left:37.8%; /*background:#fff004;*/}

/* width right column content*/  
.threecol .col3 { left:70.8%;   /*width:31.9%;*/ /*background:#fff004;*/}
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: You don't have a width set on the `.col3`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the text overflow. Thats one problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're all percentage widths, so set the `col1` div to a fixed width and this should give you what you want.

```
/* width center column content */
.threecol .col1 
{
  width:400px; 
  margin-right:50px; /*or percentage eqivalent*/
left:101.5%;
/*background:#fff004;*/
}
```

Tried in firebug, works fine :)

Comment: that actually worked, thanks. Except the text overflow fails with this, but I will try to work that out